# How to plot a user defined quadratic equation as an overlay to a scatter plot?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I am hoping that someone can suggest how I can plot a quadratic curve with a specific equation, and set x, y axes. I am using `ggplot` to create scatter plots, and am plotting some individual data points using `geom_point`, and have specified my axes as:

```
+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(2, 7)) + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2, 7, 1)) + 
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.40, .54)) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(.40, .54, 0.02))
```

I have also specified my data: `ggplot(data= data, aes(x=years,y=metric1))`

I would like to plot a quadratic curve to overlay on my plot, with a specific formula (e.g., `y = 0.4 + .025x -.002x^2`). In some cases, I wish to plot two or three different quadratic curves. I am hoping someone can assist with how I can create a curve as an overlay, or alternatively, how I can plot an equation with these specific x and y axes that I could then use as an overlay out of R.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stat_function()` to plot this curve.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 10)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=function(x) 0.4 + .025*x - .002*x^2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(2, 7), ylim = c(0.40, .54)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2, 7, 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(.40, .54, 0.02))
```

***Yielding***

[image]

You easily can add overlays, too.

***Example***

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_jitter() +
  stat_function(fun=function(x) 2.5 + 2.4*x - .5*x^2) +
  stat_function(fun=function(x) 2 + 2.4*x - .5*x^2, color="red")
```

***Yielding***

[image]